# how can i send data from editText of dialog box whose context is in mainactivity using json object?

Tags: java, android, json, api

While submitting data from editTexts of Dialog box whose context is in Home activity, the submitted button doing nothing.

host is a button on home activity,when clicked opens up a dialog box in same activity consists of two editText field (ename,eemail) and submit , cancel button. On submit getFeedback() functions called (used from ApiInterface method)

```
host.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        final Dialog d=new Dialog(context);
        d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.hostdialog);
        d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bgdialog);
        final EditText ename=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.ename);
        final EditText eemail=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.eemail);
        final Button submit=(Button)d.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        final Button clear=(Button)d.findViewById(R.id.clear);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    getFeedbacks(ename.getText().toString(),eemail.getText().toString());
                    d.dismiss();
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," ✓ Thank You, We'll contact you soon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    View v = t.getView();
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clear);
                    t.show();

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         });

         clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 d.dismiss();
             }
         });

         d.show();
     } 
});
```

and my ApiInterface code is:

```
@GET("myurl")
Call<JsonElement> getFeedbacks(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

getFeedback method consist of:-

```
    private void getFeedbacks(String user_name, String user_email){

    JSONObject paramobject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        paramobject.put("user_name",user_name);
        paramobject.put("user_email",user_email);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json,charset=utf-8"),paramobject.toString());
    Call<JsonElement> call = retrofitAPI.getFeedbacks(body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                for (int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++){
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
                    String successval =  jsonObject.optString("success");

                    if(successval.equals("0")){
                        Toast t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Request Failed, Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        View v=t.getView();

                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clear);
                        t.show();


                    }else {
                        Toast t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," ✓ Thank You, We'll contact you soon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        View v=t.getView();

                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clear);
                        t.show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Error,Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Button does not works. Please provide appropriate solution.

now i alter a little bit code as i change the call anonymously  within method. but again no work

```
          host.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
            d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.hostdialog);
            d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bgdialog);
            final EditText ename = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.ename);
            final EditText eemail = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.eemail);
            final Button submit = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.submit);
            final Button clear = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.clear);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        sendDataToServer();
                        d.dismiss();
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " ✓ Thank You, We'll contact you soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        View v = t.getView();
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clear);
                        t.show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                private void sendDataToServer() {
                    JSONObject paramobject = new JSONObject();

                    try {
                        paramobject.put("comment", ename);
                        paramobject.put("email", eemail);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json,charset=utf-8"), paramobject.toString());
                    Call<JsonElement> call = retrofitAPI.getFuturehosts((RequestBody) body);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {

                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().toString());
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                                for (int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++) {
                                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
                                    String successval = jsonObject.optString("success");

                                    if (successval.equals("0")) {
                                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Request Failed, Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        View v = t.getView();

                                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clear);
                                        t.show();


                                    } else {
                                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " ✓ Thank You, We'll contact you soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        View v = t.getView();

                                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clear);
                                        t.show();
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Error,Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });


                }
            });
            clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
            d.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you get any stacktrace messages in logcat?

Comment: From where you are calling that dialog?

Comment: yes.... when button is clicked , it shows error in getFeedback function

Comment: I thought it is obvious, but if it is not - you have to mention which error exactly.

Comment: there is another xml file for dialog, which opens in same context

Comment: okay. i will upload errors in just a min

Comment: sorry! now there is no crash in button. I think button does not works. Is there any on button click?

Comment: use debugger to check if click works, and to locate what is the problem.

Comment: are you calling this dialog from fragment?

Comment: no. I am calling it from simple xml layout

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if i remove getFeedbacks(ename.getText().toString(),eemail.getText().toString());  section from submit button, then button click works. otherwise button is not clickable

Comment: that is likely because of an exception it throws. Remove try..catch there, you don't need it. You need to fix the exception, not just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hostdialog.xml file

-button id is "submit" or not

may be that id is diffrent so the code is not working

Comment: everything is fine with dialog box, it properly opens on click. but the submit button inside dialog  box is not working

Comment: remove try catch block and then check what happen